# Supress Exponentials for text column pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am reading a csv through pd.read_csv(''), column 'item_code' has values like 123AB45CD, 456DF09, but some values are interpreted as '4E+66', '6.00E+21', how can this be treated as a normal code instead of exponential.
note: All the solutions i find over here are for float/integer columns, but the column in use 'item_code' is in string format or and Object type.

Any suggestion on how to avoid or treat this exponential for column having string values stored, as i would like to see an actual code instead of E+

Comment: Try `pd.read_csv(file, dtype = {"item_code": str})`?

Comment: this doesn't work, it still shows exponential values when i generate to_csv('file.csv')

Comment: Can you post some (more) sample data?

Comment: Item NewItem Current Volume Future Volume Current Plant CurrentRegion FutureRegion Dest
4.00E+62 ABCE0062 1000 1000 Ind ASIA ASIA East
4.00E+63 XYZ0463       2000      2000   UK        EU  EU North
4.00E+87 PQR0080 3000 3000 Nep ASIA ASIA East